# i want to wire two lights with the power coming in the first light go to the second light and then to a switch

Tags: electrical, switch

I have two lights with the power to the first light and passing through to a second light then to a switch. how is this wired?

Comment: Or this? [Power to a light, through two lights and then to a switch](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/113000/power-to-a-light-through-two-lights-and-then-to-a-switch)

Comment: isherwood is right, this question has been asked and answered and he provided excellent  (IMHO) links. It's a typical switch leg configuration and that doesn't rule out more than one fixture. +++++

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Power to a light, through two lights and then to a switch](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/113000/power-to-a-light-through-two-lights-and-then-to-a-switch)  EDIT:  Credits to isherwood for this link that he found. +