# Is this the correct way to wire multiple lights to one switch?

Tags: electrical

Is the diagram in this [DIY.SE answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/113045/35141) correct for how to wire multiple lights to one switch when power comes in the first light, and the switch is at the end of the circuit?

I followed it, but when I use my multimeter I’m only getting 90 volts at the lights, before hooking the wires up to the lights. This is a 20 amp circuit. The goal is I’m trying to control 2-3 lights with one single pole switch.

[image]

Comment: [Edit] to post some pictures of your actual connected wiring for the lights and the switch. That may reveal a mismatch between what you did and what you thought you did, or reveal questionable workmanship that should be revisited.

Comment: The only niggle here is that new code expects that you put a neutral at every switch location in case you want to upgrade to a smart switch later.

Answer (score 3):

The diagram is correct (for wiring installed up to NEC2008. The other diagram in the linked question is correct for NEC2011 and forward. You don't show nor tell what you actually have.)

In most cases either the belief that you've actually followed the diagram, or the workmanship of the splices (wirenuts per diagram) is suspect. Or you're using the meter incorrectly (*e.g.* measuring phantom voltage with the switch not turned on.) An example of not following the diagram would be "since I haven't connected the lights yet, I didn't connect the whites and the reds at the light locations yet, either."

For the splice problem something like Wago LeverNuts may improve your odds (they are harder to do poorly, or easier to do right.) Beware of off-spec direct-import unlisted imitations - buy your electrical parts at a brick and mortar store, or apply **extreme** levels of *caveat emptor*, or find that cheap parts can burn the house down the hard way...

If using wirenuts, follow the strip gauge on the wirenut package carefully, and twist them very, very tightly.

Check that you have 120VAC from the black to the white at the first light.

Comment: "twist them very, very tightly." then tighten them up some more!